# Finding a match with PyDictionary using the first sequence of letters in a word

Tags: python, pydictionary

What I like about PyDictionary when it comes to this project is that if a variable matches the name of a notable character. Einstein for example, it finds a match. What I am trying to accomplish is that when a loop runs through sequence of letters, if the first two letters or more matches the beginning (prefix) of the word, then treat that as a match.

I have tried several approaches and can't seem to get this working. Only when I pass in a whole word into a variable does PyDictionary find a match.

This is what I have tried up to now

```
#ATTEMPT 1

    import re
    import textwrap
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
    from dateutil import parser
    import nltk
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet
    nltk.download('omw-1.4')
    
    dictionary = PyDictionary()
    
    einstein = ['e', 'i', 'n', 's', 't', 'e', 'i', 'n']
    newereinstein = str(einstein)
    neweinstein = ''
    letter = ''
    for l in einstein:
        letter = letter + l
        neweinstein = letter
        meaning = dictionary.meaning(neweinstein)
        meaning = str(meaning)
        if re.search('einst', meaning):
         print('found einst...!')
         print('this is einstein found', neweinstein)
         print(meaning + 'this is the meaning of neweinstien on this loop atb the top')
    
        else:
         print('hit, was not found on this loop with re.search(' + neweinstein +  meaning)
        
         #Hits the Else statement every time
        
    
    words = dictionary.getSynonyms()
    if any(word.startswith('hit') for word in words.keys()):
        print("At least one word in the dictionary starts with the letter:", 'hit')
    else:
        print("No word in the dictionary starts with the letter:" + neweinstein)
    
    #same application, I get "doesn't have attributes keys" error with this
    
#ATTEMPT 2
    import re
    import textwrap
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
    from dateutil import parser
    import nltk
    
    
    dictionary = PyDictionary()
    
    
    newcollector = ""
    nextcollector = ""
    for t in range (len(diagonal_matrix)):
        for i in range(len(diagonal_matrix)):
         collector = diagonal_matrix[i]
         collector = str(collector)
         print("this is i", collector)
         newcollector = str(diagonal_matrix[t])
         print("this is t", newcollector)
         newcollector = newcollector + collector
         print("before the if statement", newcollector)
         meaning = dictionary.meaning(newcollector)
         if meaning is not None and len(newcollector.strip()) >= 2:
           print("this is meaning not none kicking in:", newcollector)
           nextletter = diagonal_matrix[i + 1]
           nextcollector =  newcollector + str(nextletter)
         else:
           meaning = ''
           for t in dictionary:
            if t.text.startswith(nextcollector):
             print("found first letters of a word", nextcollector)
             nextletter = diagonal_matrix[i + 1]
             nextcollector =  newcollector + str(nextletter)
        if i == len(diagonal_matrix) - 1:
          break
           print("not met condtion", newcollector)
      if dictionary.meaning(nextcollector):
        meaning = dictionary.meaning(nextcollector)
        print(meaning)
      else:
        print(collector)
    
    print("out of loop", nextcollector)
    
    #finds the meaning if any of the two letters make up a full word (hi for example) but like my other attempts doesn't find if the first two letters or more of a word matches a word
#ATTEMPT 3
    
    import re
    import textwrap
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
    from dateutil import parser
    import nltk
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet
    nltk.download('omw-1.4')
    import string
    import enchant
    
    def check_if_word_in_dictionary(word):
        dictionary = PyDictionary()
        found = False
        
        if dictionary.meaning(word, True) is not None:
            found = True
        elif len(word) > 1:
            # check if any word in the dictionary starts with the provided letters
            possible_words = [key for key in dictionary.getMeanings() if key.startswith(word)]
            if possible_words:
                found = True
                
        if found:
            print(f"You're in luck, '{word}' is found in the dictionary!")
        else:
            print(f"It appears '{word}' is NOT a word found in the dictionary.")
    
    check_if_word_in_dictionary("Einstei")
    
    #Again, only find if the letters make a full word but hits false otherwise
    

#ATTEMPT 4
    import re
    import textwrap
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
    from dateutil import parser
    import nltk
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet
    nltk.download('omw-1.4')
    
    
    dictionary = PyDictionary()
    print(dictionary)
    
    
    oriword = ['e', 'i', 'n', 's', 't', 'e', 'i', 'n']
    
    
    
    syncount = 0
    lemmacount = 0
    nextcombo = ''
    for letter in oriword:
     print('this is the letter before the loop check ' + str(letter))
     nextcombo = nextcombo + str(letter)
     print('this is next combo ' + str(nextcombo))
     synsets = wordnet.synsets(nextcombo)
     antonym = dictionary.antonym(nextcombo)
     print('this is the synonyms: ' + str(antonym))
     print('this is a meaning:' + str(meaning))
     if synsets:
        for synset in synsets:
            print('this is synsets loop ')
            syncount += 1
            print('this is syncount: '+ str(syncount))
            for lemma in synset.lemmas():
                lemmacount += 1
                print('this is lemma count: ' + str(lemmacount))
                antonym = str(antonym)
                newword = str(oriword)
                print('nextcombo:' + str(nextcombo))
                print('this is the word before the if statement ' + str(newword))
                nextcombo = nextcombo + str('') 
                for d in dictionary:
                 print('i am' +  str(d))
                 if d.startswith(nextcombo):
                  print('this is the starts with function kicking in' + str(nextcombo))
    
                    
                  print('found word')
                  print('this is meaning that is not None: ' + str(meaning))
                  print('this is the word within the if statement', nextcombo)
                  print('this is the lemma name: ', str(lemma.name))
                  print('this is the lemma loop ', str(antonym))
                  print('this is the synset: ', str(synset))
                  break
                 else:
                    continue
                 break
     if dictionary.meaning(nextcollector):         
    
    
            else:
                print('not found')


    
    #Again, this hits the else statement every time
```

Please ignore the indentation. I may have cocked that up pasting in here from four different projects. I am well familiar with the indentation rules of Python so disregard these errors.

Your help is very much appreciated. I am stuck. thank you.

Comment: `PyDictionary` cannot search for a partial word based on the first few characters of a word.  For instance if you provide this input `eins` then `PyDictionary` will return either not found or NONE.  You have to provide a word that might be in the source that `PyDictionary` queries.